# Detecting screen capture in progress

Tags: macos, cocoa, screenshot, screen-capture

How can I detect when a screen shot selection (cmd-shift-4) is in progress?

I have a custom window that I’m trying to make behave like a menu (it comes out of a status item). Part of this behavior is dismissing it when the user clicks on something else, which I detect using a CGEventTap. One case where I *don’t* want a click to dismiss is when it’s the start of a screen shot selection. Is there any way to detect this?

I'm talking about the "capture some of your screen" feature described here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5775

Comment: do you want to stop the capture from happening or do you just want to alter the behavior of command-shift-4?

Comment: Neither. I want to detect when a click is the start of a capture selection, and not dismiss my menu window in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've found the answer: check whether `/usr/sbin/screencapture` is running.

I opened Activity Monitor, sorted by process ID, and hit cmd-shift-4. `screencapture` appeared at the top of the list for the duration of the screen capture.

Comment: Above works if you are not detecting for whatever security reason. Otherwise the user can rename the process, and then run that via terminal:
`cp /usr/sbin/screencapture ~/kernel_cromulent | ./kernel_cromulent file1.png`. The correct way is detecting the API calls that screencapture is using.

Comment: Looking for the screencapture process worked well enough for my purpose, but you're right that it wouldn't be sufficient if there are security concerns.